# c# .net Http response 411 length required when length is included

Tags: c#, .net, http, post

I'm trying to get a simple response from a local .net site of my own. (Really I'm just trying to see what the content-body looks like from the server side.) Here is the controller method that's sending the response:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            data.Add(value);
            var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + (data.Count-1).ToString());
            msg.Content = new StringContent(value);
            return msg;
        }
```

And here is the code that's making the request:

```
        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://localhost:50203/api/Values"); 
        request.Method = "POST";

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] requestBody = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("grant_type=client_credentials"));
            request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
            dataStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            myString = reader.ReadToEnd();


        }
```

I'm getting the response message: `HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length`. But as you can see I DO assign the content length in the line: `request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;`.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It looks like you're not assigning the `request.ContentLength` until *after* you send the request, so how would that help?

Comment: Duh you're right. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I still don't have an answer for you. I'm not sure how you'd know the length to include in the request before you get the response. Kind of a catch 22 problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense - **you set the content length after the request has been sent**, then you **write the body to the response stream** and finally **you read the exact same content you just wrote**

Comment: yonisha you are right. I am new to using the HttpWebRequest, and therefore confused the ResponseStream and RequestStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from itsme86 I was able to see what was happening. It had to do with misunderstanding the HttpWebRequest method. I was trying to set the content length and write to the request after I'd already posted it using the `GetResponse` method. I should have posted the length first. This wasn't a particularly good question, and no one else should answer.